# Android App runs in emulator but says "Not Installed"

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I can run my app and do things fine on the emulator in Eclipse.  When I go "Home" in the emulator and try to run the App again (by clicking its icon in the Apps folder) it says "App isn't installed"

EDIT: Also I am not being prompted to give permissions on the device itself (emulator or Nexus 7)

Also, when I export the apk to a real device (nexus 7 running 4.2.1) the app does not run and it indicates it is not installed.  Any thoughts?

Here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.killerapprejji"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<permission android:name="NFC" android:permissionGroup="NFC"></permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ninjahead"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:allowClearUserData="true" android:logo="@drawable/ninjahead" android:persistent="true" android:permission="android.permission.NFC">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
          <data android:mimeType="application/com.killerapprejji.attacked"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>  
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AttackActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/attack_button"></activity>
    <activity android:launchMode="standard" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/menu_settings" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:noHistory="false" android:description="@string/menu_settings" android:configChanges="keyboard" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:parentActivityName="@string/title_activity_main" android:icon="@drawable/ninjahead" android:name=".SetInfo"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DefendActivity" android:label="@string/defend_button" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
    <activity android:name="DisplayInteractions" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/Stats" android:parentActivityName="@string/title_activity_main"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: there usually a messages in LOGCAT that help you determine what's going on

Comment: anything in particular I should ook for?  Nothing has caught my eye thus far

Comment: also I am not being prompted to give permissions on the Nexus 7

Comment: look at your logcat or Android console output. It should show something like this: http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/2696/screenshot20121203at121.png | and yes, no permissions asked, when you deploy via USB.

Comment: You may have a stale launcher shortcut.  Uninstall all historic versions and variants of your app, then reinstall.  There is no permission dialog with an adb or eclipse install.

Comment: The permission dialog thing was throwing me off.  Once I realized I shouldn't be seeing one, I found the issue as stated in the solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two problems:

1)  I need

```
<uses-permission ... />
```

instead of

```
<permission ... />
```

2)

```
<application ... android:permission="android.permission.NFC">
```

does not need to contain the second part.